# How to allow copy paste from a extension popup in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have created [a webextension](https://github.com/Sjord/messpostage) with a popup window:

[image: Browser extension popup window]

I want the user to be able to copy/paste the contents of this popup. This works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox the text cannot be selected. If you drag with your mouse over the text nothing happens.

I tried inspecting and changing the CSS (maybe there's a default [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)?), but without success.
How can I enable text selection in my extension's popup window?

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**: add `-moz-user-select: text` to the body element of the popup.

There is indeed a default [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select).

You can inspect the CSS of the popup using the following steps:

- Navigate to about:debugging and enable add-on debugging.
- Click the Debug link next to your addon.
- Click the ellipses in the top right corner and select "Disable popup auto-hide".

[image]

- Open your popup.
- In the developer tools, select another frame by clicking the frame button in the top right corner.

[image]

- Open the inspector. As you can see there is a -moz-user-select CSS rule:

[image]

So the fix is to add a CSS rule in your popup CSS like this:

```
body { -moz-user-select: text; }
```

Setting this to `auto` doesn't work. Other possible values are [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select).